# Embedded PDF displays just a file name in IE and works correctly in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The Embedded PDF in my HTML page not working correctly just shows a file name on the page but works fine in Chrome

```
<object data="content/en_US/download_assets/1.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="{{width}}" height="{{height}}"><a href="content/en_US/download_assets/1.pdf" class="isDisabled">1.pdf</a></object>
```

Height and Width ill map externally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately IE is not the greatest browser and requires some help to view a pdf

Open Internet Explorer and choose Tools > Manage Add-ons.
Under Add-on Types, select Toolbars and Extensions.
In the Show menu, choose All add-ons.
In the list of add-ons, select Adobe PDF Reader.
Click the Enable button.

Comment: That is why web developers often use chrome and firefox instead of IE